# Automated node running

Tags: ros, roslaunch, node

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is there a way to automatically run a node using/inside a C++/Python program? Say some event happened and I want to run this node, then another event happened and I want to close the node. Or perhaps a launch file?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9631/automated-node-running/) by [Homer Manalo](https://answers.ros.org/users/74/homer-manalo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 475 on 2011-04-03

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This similar question I asked a while back might help you out.

http://answers.ros.org/question/501/spawn-and-kill-nodes-from-nodessmach

---

Originally posted by [Miguel Prada](https://answers.ros.org/users/164/miguel-prada/) with karma: 1071 on 2011-04-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

A ROS node is just an executable, so you can run (and kill) it as you run any other executable from your program (for C++ see `man system` or `man popen`). The main problem might be, that ros stuff that is setup in your bashrc (e.g. the environment variables ROS_PACKAGE_PATH and ROS_MASTER_URI) are not available. In that case you might be successful running a bash to interpret your command. You may need to run it as interactive shell "-i" to make sure it executes .bashrc. So altogether something like system("bash -i -c roslaunch somepackage somefile.launch") should work. To kill a node you could use `rosnode kill [node]` started in the above way.

---

Originally posted by [Felix Endres](https://answers.ros.org/users/113/felix-endres/) with karma: 6468 on 2011-04-03

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4